# No Ethernet on a Intel NUC6CAY @ Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, ethernet

i have an Intel NUC6CAY with a "LAN Realtek 8111HN" on board. But it didn't show up.
I use a fresh installed Ubuntu 20.04. Because previous Mint installation has same problem after update to 20.04. Before 20.04 I used 19.x or 18.x, don't remember. But LAN was working.

**Edit: BIOS-Update works for me. See updated outputs below**

`ifconfig -a`
Shows lo and wlp2s0 (WLAN).

`lspci -nnk |grep -a3 Ethernet` shows nothing.

```
dmesg |grep e1000e
[  198.740755] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[  198.740758] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
```

```
 sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:02:00.0
       Logischer Name: wlp2s0
       Version: 10
       Seriennummer: de:ad:co:de:ba:se
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 ip=192.168.2.42 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: irq:129 memory:91100000-91101fff
```

All this C&P was done after I even downloaded and compilethe `r8168-8.048.03.tar.bz2` from https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software.

I am not a regular unix user. All this was done by unsystematical researching and try and error.

Any sugesstion what to do to use the ethernet connection?

Update/Edit:
`sudo journalctl -b 0` returns over 11.000 lines of log. looking for `eth`
gives me `systemd-udevd[378]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable. kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3`
Maybe you can specifiy what are you looking for. Found nothing for realtek (exept soundcard) gigabit, ethernet

I removed all lines which math`(.*)\(wlp2s0\):(.*)\n` in next log:

```
sudo journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
-- Reboot --
Aug 12 22:14:24 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263264.9381] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting... (for the first time)
Aug 12 22:14:24 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263264.9383] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
Aug 12 22:14:24 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263264.9854] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.0048] manager[0x5562be1cf030]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.0049] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.3240] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.3241] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "homerunner"
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.3246] dns-mgr[0x5562be1b7290]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=symlink, plugin=systemd-resolved
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.3322] rfkill0: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.1/0000:02:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0) (driver iwlwifi)
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.3333] manager[0x5562be1cf030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.3333] manager[0x5562be1cf030]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.3576] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.3665] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.3877] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.4009] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.4026] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.4032] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.4036] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.4037] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.4039] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.4095] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.4096] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.4097] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <warn>  [1597263265.4104] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.4192] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.4198] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <warn>  [1597263265.4977] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.5160] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.5218] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.6484] sup-iface[0x5562be1dc120,wlp2s0]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.6530] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp2s0 created
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.6540] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.6554] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263265.6577] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 12 22:14:25 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <warn>  [1597263265.6694] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
Aug 12 22:14:28 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263268.9714] policy: auto-activating connection 'NetofNet' (275c1c77-ac5b-4117-8803-a0ae7870c34e)
Aug 12 22:14:28 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263268.9767] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.0003] Config: added 'ssid' value 'NetofNet'
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.0003] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.0004] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.0004] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.0004] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.0004] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.0194] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: ready -> authenticating
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.0220] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.0340] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.0437] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.0921] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.1406] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.1500] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.1512] policy: set 'NetofNet' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.1555] manager: startup complete
Aug 12 22:14:29 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263269.4590] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Aug 12 22:14:30 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263270.5744] policy: set 'NetofNet' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
Aug 12 22:14:33 homerunner NetworkManager[717]: <info>  [1597263273.1526] agent-manager: agent[a5afc4246fa6048e,:1.44/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
```

**Outputs after BIOS Update**

```
ifconfig -a
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 94:c6:91:a2:3f:b2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 128  base 0x5000 
...
```

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       Produkt: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:02:00.0
       Logischer Name: wlp2s0
       Version: 10
       Seriennummer: 34:e1:2d:ca:77:86
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 ip=192.168.0.25 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       Ressourcen: irq:130 memory:91200000-91201fff
  *-network
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:03:00.0
       Logischer Name: enp3s0
       Version: 15
       Seriennummer: 94:c6:91:a2:3f:b2
       Kapazität: 1Gbit/s
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.00-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       Ressourcen: irq:128 ioport:e000(Größe=256) memory:91104000-91104fff memory:91100000-91103fff
```

Comment: `sudo journalctl -b 0` will show logs from the beginning of the current boot, including the detection/non detection of your card, and `sudo journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

Comment: Is the ethernet interface enabled in your BIOS?

Comment: @waltinator i added some information.

Comment: @heynnema yes. LAN is enabled.

Comment: Show me the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: AYAPLCEL.86A.0052.2018.0627.1943

Comment: May we please see: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`

Comment: @chili555 no output

Comment: Please see my answer and report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Sorry too busy at the moment. I try it at the weekend.

Comment: @heynnema:
 Update done.

Output in this comment messed up. I update my outputs in root comment.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

Intel NUC6CAY

You have BIOS version AYAPLCEL.86A.0052.2018.0627.1943.

There appears to be a newer BIOS available, AYAPLCEL.86A.0066, dated 12/17/2019, and can be downloaded [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/95078/Intel-NUC-Kit-NUC6CAYS) or [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29319/BIOS-Update-AYAPLCEL-86A-?product=95078).

BIOS Update Instructions are [here](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/29319/eng/NUC-BIOS-Update-Readme.pdf).

Note: Verify that I have the correct web page for your model. It covers two different systems.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

Comment: Thanks, that was the hint that finaly worked.

Comment: @JensB. Great news! Please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JensB. Status please...

Comment: @JensB. Status please...